# Why would Python execute my code correctly while I do have an obvious error?

Tags: python-3.x

While I was practicing some if statements in Python, I ran into a weird problem that made me confused about how *exactly* does Python execute programs.
referring to the following code:

```
x = 63

if x >= 0 and x <= 9:
    print("X is One digit, and it is: " , x)
elif x >= 10 and x <= 99:
    print("X is Two digits, and it is: " , x) # the error begins here
elif x >= 100 and x <= 999:
    print("X is Three digits, and it is: " + x)
else:
    print("X is a negative number, and it is: " + x)
```

If the value of x is between 0-99 the program will work correctly. Though as obvious it contains an error. why I still get an output. This made me really curious about how Python executes programs!

Comment: I'm still looking for the "obvious" error

Comment: The `+` operator concatenates strings, but `x` is an int. The branch simply wasn't reached.

Comment: In the print command of the second elif
it is ("X is Two digits, and it is: " , x)
where there should be a plus NOT a comma.

Comment: That's a valid and common use of the `print` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is syntactically valid Python, but the `+` operation will fail between a string and an int, but is allowed between a string and a string.

The comma, on the other hand, is valid, since `print` works on any number of objects. You can tell by calling `help` on a function object to see what arguments it accepts. `print` will add an extra space between arguments by default, so that space after the colon in the string is probably also a mistake.

Python doesn't force static type checking. If you're used to a statically-typed language, this may be surprising. This kind of type error doesn't happen until runtime, but doesn't happen at all if the branch is not executed. You can use an external static type checker like mypy, plus Python's type annotation syntax to catch this kind of type error even before running the program.

Many bugs in Python are hard to detect until the code is executed. That's why you should write tests to execute all of your code. Syntax errors will still show up before you run the program though.

Python also allows chained comparisons, so

```
0 <= x <= 9
```

would be more pythonic.

Comment: So you mean that even if I have a run time error the program will work correctly if the error isn't reached!

Comment: Won't that be considered as a bug if I couldn't catch it myself!

Comment: @SalehHussain That's what testing is for! :) (Also pylint etc.)